# App crashes (only) after installation

Tags: iphone, memory, installation

I compiled an fine working project (before compiled with 3.1.3) now with 3.2.1

Now after installation from XCode to Device it needs quite long
to install and after it runs a few seconds later i just see for short
a red alert at the top (can't read, it's too fast) and the app closes itself.

When I then start the installed app... all is fine!

So it's really just after installation, but what could this be and how
to avoid. I dont like that my Users have this also, or could this just
a bug while installing from xcode to device?

Thx
chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible from your description that xcode is unable to start the app in the debugger.

Likely causes for this could be:

1. You have an entitlements.plist file where get-task-allow is set to false.
2. You're signing the app with an adhoc certificate instead of the development one

The console output (window->organizer) may provide a clue.